# I think I have done necessary code signing work but build still failing in Ionic

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, ionic-framework, code-signing

Building an Ionic app to try and test on my iPhone. I downloaded XCode last night and went in and created a profile with my Apple ID, as well as changing the bundle identified in the "General" and "Signing & Capabilities" tab. However when I run "ionic cordova build ios --prod" I get the error:

```
error: No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'io.ionic.starter'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build ios exited with exit code 65.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

It seems to me as though I have done the necessary code signing procedures that I read from Ionic's website, so I am unsure why it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

To run the app in your iPhone there are several steps, check these:

- You have created your app ID in the website.
- You have created your provisioning profile in the website, and downloaded to your computer and added to your Mac (web -> download profile -> double-click)
- You have created a development certificate (search how to create a certificate using a Certificate Signing Request generated in your Mac ) and then downloaded that certificate and added to your Mac.

There are two certificates. Distribution certificate is used to publish the app, but development certificate is used simply to run the project in your iPhone, you need that.

But honestly, it's all much easier if you use XCode instead of the console. In the console run the command without --prod, to apply ionic changes to the iOS project. Then if you want to run the app, it's easier if you open XCode and just click play.

With XCode there's the option "Automatically manage signing" that will handle most of this for you automatically. You just have to login to your account using XCode (it will prompt you) and let it do it for you.